# Diets promoted by different Rabbis throughout history

Tags: history, food, rabbis, health-safety-shmira

I was curious if there was any information about the sages or other known historical Rabbis who promoted diets for physical/spiritual health.

Obviously, Kosher is Kosher but did anyone ever suggest following a specific type of diet for the benefit of one's body and spiritual health?

Answer (score 1):

So in terms of first promoting physical health:

1) The Ritva on Shavuous 27a says one should avoid unhealthy food.

2) Similarly, the Tur (OC 155) says expressly how it is a mitzvah to watch one’s self to make sure he stays healthy in order to serve Hashem.

As far as diet:
The Rambam writes extensively about how to eat healthy in the fourth perek of hilchos deos [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.4?lang=bi) and concludes:

כָּל הַמַּנְהִיג עַצְמוֹ בִּדְרָכִים אֵלּוּ שֶׁהוֹרֵינוּ אֲנִי עָרֵב לוֹ שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּא לִידֵי חלִי כָּל יָמָיו עַד שֶׁיַּזְקִין הַרְבֵּה וְיָמוּת וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְרוֹפֵא. וְיִהְיֶה גּוּפוֹ שָׁלֵם וְעוֹמֵד עַל בֻּרְיוֹ כָּל יָמָיו. אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן הָיָה גּוּפוֹ רַע מִתְּחִלַּת בְּרִיָּתוֹ. אוֹ אִם הָיָה רָגִיל בְּמִנְהָג מִן הַמִּנְהָגוֹת הָרָעִים מִתְּחִלַּת מוֹלַדְתּוֹ. אוֹ אִם תָּבוֹא מַכַּת דֶּבֶר אוֹ מַכַּת בַּצֹּרֶת לָעוֹלָם

Whosoever trains himself in these ways which were pointed out, I assure him that he will encounter no sickness all of his days, until he will die of old age; he will need no doctor; his body will be sound and well preserved throughout his life, unless his body be bad from its very formation or if there be a visitation of a pestilence or famine upon the world.

Also refer to משנה ברורה סעיף קטן מה on שלחן ערוך קע:כב who provides a helpful list of nutritional advice.

יזהר מאד שלא לאכול לב בהמה חיה ועוף [מ"א] כתב א"ר בשם של"ה ייטיב לבו בסעודתו אם מעט ואם הרבה יאכל פתו בשמחה. יאכל הטוב והמועיל לו לרפואה ולא מה שערב לו לפי שעה. ולא יישן סמוך לאכילה אלא ימתין אחר אכילה ועיין ברמב"ם הלכות דעות פ"ו שהאריך בדברים אלו והנהגתן. גם האריך בשל"ה ליזהר מרבוי אכילה ושתיה אלא יאכל וישתה רק להעמיד ולהברות את גופו מזומן לעבודת הנפש ובזה כל סעודותיו הוין סעודת מצוה וע"ש בא"ר שהביא עוד כמה ענינים הנוגעים בענין זה

The Ra'avad also (I need to check up where exactly) also details a diet but his more geared towards mastering self control. So he advises that you first start by leaving one forkful of food from your plate at the end of every meal. Upon mastering this you move on to another forkful from another one of the elements on the plate e.g. you leave a forkful of meat and potato etc. once being able to do this you then move on to refraining from the 'best bit' of the food e.g. your most favourite part like the gooey cheese on a pizza.

Comment: The Mishna Berurah there is not bringing nutritional advice as far as i can see. Most of your sources are incredibly generic "eat healthy" without specifying a specific diet (except Dr Rambam of course)